# removing many-to-many relationship with composite key in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

I have a many to many relationship with composite key. Now I want to remove one item from the join entity class which is one row from database. How can I do this?

side 1

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tag", , orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TagDefinitionProject> tagProjects = new ArrayList<TagDefinitionProject>();
```

side 2

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project", , orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TagDefinitionProject> tagProjects = new ArrayList<TagDefinitionProject>();
```

Join class:

```
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tag", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Tag tag;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_project", referencedColumnName = "id_project")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
    private Project project;
```

PK class:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_tag")
    private Integer tag;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_project")
    private Integer project;
```

In my service layer code I'm trying to do this but it doesn't work.

```
 TagDefinitionProject t = tagDao.findByTagAndProject(i,j);
 tdpDao.remove(t);
```

Comment: I had the same problem, where I had a many to many relationship and I tried remove one item from the join entity class, it did not work, to resolve this problem, I removed  the orphanRemoval and CascadeType properties here: **@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tag", , orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TagDefinitionProject> tagProjects = new ArrayList<TagDefinitionProject>();** and manipulated manually. Sorry for my bad English